# Making a new database onto existing AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, aws

I know that we can create multiple databases on a single AWS RDS instance. I have an existing MySQL instance and was wondering what steps are required to create an additional database on that server? Does it involve creation of a new user and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE DATABASE db2;
```

There does *not* have to be a different user for each database.  But you might want to do it if you want to keep, say, two applications, each using one of the databases, from accidentally stepping on each other.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.* TO 'user1'@'host-name' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db2.* TO 'user2'@'host-name' IDENTIFIED BY 'password2';
```

Usually I have a separate user for each database; sometimes I have a user that touches multiple databases.

(This answer applies to MySQL and MariaDB in general.)